# How to parse the "GMT+hours:minutes" or "GMT-hours:minutes" using SimpleDateFormat in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

For example, I want to parse the string below:

```
Tue Sep 28 18:02:24 GMT+08:00 2010
```

And I use the pattern for the `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzzzzzzz yyyy");
```

But I keep getting the `ParseException`.
How to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, It seems the Android's document is not pretty correct. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html It also not support the 'v' pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use one z, as in the examples [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone)

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I found the solution here.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

But what's the difference between using 'z' and 'Z' here?
Are they the same?

Comment: You hit the return a few sec. before. :)

Comment: z and Z are "general time zone" vs. "RFC 822 time zone"

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have many z's it work.